# Почему при беззнаковом сдвиге байта вправо не обнуляется старший разряд?

Tags: java

```
byte b = -1;   // b = -1  1111_1111
b <<= 1;       // b = -2  1111_1110
b >>>= 1;      // b = -1  1111_1111
```

В комментариях - значение b в debug.
В последней строке b должно стать 0111_1111, ведь применялся беззнаковый сдвиг вправо. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Ошибка" в спецификации Java. Все [операции с целыми числами](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) выполняются с 32-битной точностью, и их результатом является `int` (кроме случаев, когда один из операндов - `long`).

Код

```
b >>>= 1;
```

эквивалентен

```
b = (byte)( b >>> 1 );
```

[Оператор сдвига](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) выполняет [unary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1) для каждого аргумента, приводя их типы к `int` (или к `long`). Расширение `byte` до `int` сохраняет значение, т.е. `(byte)-2` становится `(int)-2`, отсюда и появляется единица слева в результате сдвига.

Для получения нужного результата можно написать так:

```
b = (byte)((b & 0xFF) >>> 1);
```